# Scopes with AR::Relation works in app but fails in functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p392 and rails 3.2.17

I have devices. A device belongs to a device type, and a device status.
In my Device model, i have setup dynamic scope as follow:

```
DeviceStatus.all.each do |device_status|
    scope device_status.name, where(:device_status_id => device_status.id)
end
```

the name property of device status only allows [0-9a-zA-Z]
It basically creates a scope for each device status I have in the DB.

I have 3 device statuses, Active, Unused and Obsolete

In the console, I can use:

```
DeviceType.all.each do |d|
    DeviceStatus.all.each do |s|
        p d.devices.send(s.name).count
    end
end
```

And I get the expected result: the count of different statuses, per device type.

I have this in a view and it works flawlessly. I also use this method to filter my index.html.erb from the controller using dynamic scopes selected by the user. I also use the same principle with other classes for filtering the index.html.erb

However, my problem appears when I run my functional tests, where I get the following error message in my view:

```
undefined method for 'Active' []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

If I try to avoid associations and just replace d.devices.send() in my loop with Devices.send() i get:

```
undefined method for 'Active' #<Class:0xxxxxxxx>
```

Has anyone seen that before ?

Comment: `Active` should not be a method when defining your scopes you should downcase those status' ruby method names are lowercase and snake case so these methods should be `active`, `unused` and `obsolete`. Also you should post the code that is having issues so we can see if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Are there any DeviceStatuses in your test environment? Do they exist when you call `DeviceStatus.all`?

Comment: @engineersmnky: downcasing these will not solve my issue.

Comment: @muistooshort: Yes, I have 4 of them, one more than in my dev environment.

Comment: @jdel I was not suggesting it would I am sorry if that was implicated. I was simply stating that you should use proper convention for method calls. I still highly suggest posting the tests that are failing not the code that is working.

Comment: Does it work if you manually define the scopes? Just because the statuses are there when you go looking doesn't mean that they're there when the class is loaded. The class could be loaded *before* the `device_statuses` table is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

When executing rake test:functionals, the database is cleared and fixtures are loaded in the database after the models are processed.

So when the Device model is loaded, there is no DeviceStatus in the database, resulting in the model not creating the scopes. The fixtures are loaded after that and the test fails when trying to call a scope that doesn't exist on my Device relation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `d.devices` will be an array of `ActiveRecord` objects as `DeviceType` will have many `Devices`. I think you needs to do one of the following as par your requirement:

```
p d.devices[0].send(s.name).count
```

or

```
DeviceType.all.each do |d|
    DeviceStatus.all.each do |s|
        d.devices..each do |device|
           p device.send(s.name).count
        end   
    end
end
```

Comment: The code in my example above works in a view, when I browse to it, but fails when I run a functional test. Your code above doesn't do what I want at all.
You are right on the first part though, it is an collection of AR::Relation that I want to scope using the dynamic scopes i create.